# How is Java's String#intern() method implemented?

Tags: java, string, string-interning

I tried to look at Java's `String#intern()` method, but it's `public native String intern();`

In general, how is interning implemented? In String's case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Sun Java, start with `JVM_InternString`, on line ~3639 of [`jvm.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#l3639).  Technically, the actual String method is in [`java/lang/String.c`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/native/java/lang/String.c), but it immediately calls `JVM_InternString`.  You can continue to [`StringTable::intern`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/classfile/symbolTable.cpp) in `symbolTable.cpp`.

In a more abstract sense, the purpose of interning is to map equivalent strings to a single canonical one.

Comment: Hmm, it would have been nice to show some code in the question. All the links are broken now. Thank you for the good start though.

Comment: All the links work fine for me. They definitely aren't broken anymore!