# Can we access or query the Java String intern (constant) pool?

Tags: java, string, pool

Is there are way to access the contents of the String constant pool within our own program?

Say I have some basic code that does this:

```
String str1 = "foo";
String str2 = "bar";
```

There are now 2 strings floating around in our String constant pool. Is there some way to access the pool and print out the above values or get the current total number of elements currently contained in the pool?

i.e.

```
StringConstantPool pool = new StringConstantPool();
System.out.println(pool.getSize()); // etc
```

Comment: There will be many, many more strings in the constant pool---those that come from the JDK classes and any of your dependencies. Note that the string pool is filled at **class loading** time, and not when actual code which refers to the string constants is run.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik interesting point, I would not have assumed that strings defined in the JDK classes would have been loaded into the pool.

Comment: It is true for any class, including the JDK classes, once the class itself has been loaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot directly access the `String intern pool`.

As per [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) `String intern pool` is:

> A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained **privately** by the
>   class String.

However String objects can be added to this pool using String's `intern()` method.

[**`java.lang.String.intern()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) returns an interned String, that is, one that has an entry in the global String pool. If the String is not already in the global String pool, then it will be added.

**Programmatically** you can follow this approach:

1. Declare `Set<String> StringConstantPool = new HashSet<String>();`
2. call `String.intern()`
3. Add returned `String` value into this pool `StringConstantPool`

Comment: The Javadoc has been wrong and indeed self-contradictory on this point forever. It can't be true both that the pool is 'initially empty' *and* that 'all string literals and constant-valued string expressions are interned', and it is also untrue that the String class is responsible for the latter. It is in fact wrong to describe that as interning at all.

Comment: I believe by writing `initially empty` they mean to say that when JVM loads this pool is empty.

Comment: It is not only private from OOP point of view, but actually [implemented as a native method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323608/how-is-javas-stringintern-method-implemented). This means that it is not possible to access it even with a reflection.